# Django2 ListView using two models

Tags: django

I want to access two models from ListView in order to show data in a template_list

models.py

```
class MdCategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Nombre',
    )
class MdEntrada(models.Model):  
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        MdCategoria,
        verbose_name='Categorías',
    )
```

view.py

```
class VwCategoria(BaseView, ListView):
    template_name = 'ap_blog/categoria.html'
    model = MdEntrada
```

¿ How to set query access to MdCategoria from VwCategoria ?
¿ How to show MdCategoria and MdEntrada datas using template tags in categoría.html ?

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
 class VwCategoria(BaseView, ListView):
         template_name = 'ap_blog/categoria.html'
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(VwCategoria, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['MdCategoria'] = About.objects.all()
            context['MdEntrada'] = MdEntrada.objects.all()
            return context
```